# Telebot ошибка 400

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Полный текст ошибки:

> (**init**.py:648 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: invalid file HTTP URL specified: URL host is empty"

Код:

```py
import requests
import telebot
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bot = telebot.TeleBot('---------')
headers = {'User-Agent': '---------'}


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text.lower() == "привет":
        urlweather = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=google+погода+волгодонск&sxsrf=ALiCzsZsJDdrnxCRqMgSBfmnQf_X7ebpAg%3A1651476478993&ei=_odvYt31O5T8rgSN3b6IBQ&ved=0ahUKEwjd7ImnpcD3AhUUvosKHY2uD1EQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=google+погода+волгодонск&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIGCAAQFhAeMgkIABDJAxAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46CggAEEcQsAMQyQM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6CAgAEIAEEMkDOgUIABCABDoICAAQDRAFEB5KBAhBGABKBAhGGABQyAFYsxBghBRoAXABeACAAWmIAYQIkgEDOS4ymAEAoAEByAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp'
        wresponse = requests.get(urlweather, headers=headers)
        # fullpage - 1) url 2) заголовки(типа хар-ка устройства)!
        wsoup = BeautifulSoup(wresponse.content, 'html.parser')
        weather_image = wsoup.find('img', {'class': 'wob_tci'})['src']
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, weather_image)
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: если я просто вывожу через print в консоль url изображения, то такой ошибки не возникает
возникает только при отправке картинки через telebot

Comment: Однако weather_image не картинка, а только ссылка на картинку.

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=weather_image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Понял, в чём заключалась проблема.
Изображение поступало в виде "**//ssl.gstatic.com/onebox/weather/64/cloudy.png**", что не являлось url, так что я просто приписал "**https:**" в начале и всё исправилось!